# Python class attributes

Tags: python

From Yaniv Aknin's post about [Python innards: object 102](https://tech.blog.aknin.name/2010/05/19/pythons-innards-objects-102/#comments). There is a statement like this.

> getting attributes on a type is directly wired to dictionary assignment for the type instance’s private dictionary pointed to by the type’s structure.

I’m struggling to understand what it means.

In the post, it uses the term `type` over `class`. So I read it as a `class` has a type as well and it is `type`, and `type` has slots to use the class’s dict to retrieve and set attributes. BUT why getting an attribute is wired to dictionary assignment? Isn’t that suppose to be the set operation?

Comment: Honestly, that is a very awkwardly phrased sentence. I *think* all it means to express is that getting/setting class attributes is the same as modifying the type dict.

Comment: I am guessing the author is talking about the `inst.__dict__` itself, which is `__dict__` assigned to `inst`; in other words, `inst.__dict__` was phrased as "dictionary assignment" here.  A less awkward phrasing could instead be "getting attributes on a type is retrieving a value from the private dictionary assigned to the instance".

Comment: A class is an object just like every other object/variable/function in python, it has a `__dict__` attribute which could be described as the "type instance’s private dictionary", this is where the class attributes are stored. Classes generally derive/subclass from the built-in `type` which is why they could be described as "types"

Comment: Assuming `C` is a type (e.g., a class) I think that "getting attributes" means referencing the attribute as in `C.A` is the same as `C.__dict__["A"]`. Its confusing that the sentence says "dictionary assignment", which is the opposite of getting something. You can assign `C.B = 'foo'` but you can't assign `C.B.__dict__['B'] = 'foo'` because that's not a standard `dict`. Its a `dict_proxy` whose `__setitem__` (well, really the C equivalent) blocks the operation. Class variables can be read by an instance `self.A` and `dict_proxy` just makes that kind of thing more efficient.

Comment: @IainShelvington -this question is very focused, I don't see why it is closed. Getting attributes on a type IS NOT tied to dictionary assignment. They are opposite things. OP's confusion is well justified.

Comment: @tdelaney The bad wording and misunderstanding of an article is not the basis for a question. The article even mentions retrieving attributes and not just assignment "These functions use the dictionary each type has and pointed to by tp_dict to store/retrieve the attributes"

Comment: Thank you, guys, for all the explanation. I will read that article again with what you just explained in my mind. If I'm still confused after that, I can try to make this question more concrete.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't worked with an example yet this may help. An object in python has a special attribute **dict** which is, "The namespace supporting arbitrary function attributes."
[**dict** doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        # self here is person
        # set its attributes age and name
        self.age = 21
        self.name = "Bob"

# person object is of type Person
person = Person()

print( person.__dict__ )
# {'age': 21, 'name': 'Bob'}

# Add a new variable to person object namespace
person.new_var = "a_new_value"

print( person.__dict__ )
# {'age': 21, 'name': 'Bob', 'new_var': 'a_new_value'}
```

Notice a Person object has the dictionary **dict** which contains the key value pairs for its attributes.

Comment: Except the question is about type objects (`Person` in your example) and how its different than instances. `Person._dict__` doesn't work the same way as `person.__dict__`. And `person.__dict__["somevar"]` isn't the same as `person.somevar either. The first will not fall back to class level variables.

Comment: The little bit that I know is take the line person = Person(). Python translates this underneath to Person.__init__(person) for the constructor for example. The instance is the argument here, whereas __init__ belongs to the type. If I can plug a former teacher of mine, here you can check this out or search in the text for Fundamental Equation of Object-Oriented Programming (https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/class.txt). And yes Person is a class so its __dict__ contains attributes that support python class behavior such as __init__,  __dict__, and __module__. Hope this helps.

Comment: Your answer is right... its just not related to the question. The link references a discussion of how python types (e.g., `Person`) work at the C level. And how a type object, even though it is an instance object, doesn't work the same as a regular instance like `person`. In fact, C level extensions can do many crazy things.

Comment: Okay I see, then it's more complicated than I thought and I didn't understand it correctly sorry to say. I can leave the answers here though if you want. Hope someone else is better able to answer.